# When using css overlay, there is leftover white space at bottom of page?

Tags: css

I am using this CSS to apply overlay to my layout :

```
div.hopscotch-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .3;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

But I am facing the problem where there waste a white space at bottom of the page. Left side is my menu bar and right side is content. The white space appear after overlay applied. How to solve this problem?

[image]

sample : http://jsfiddle.net/plainkeyman/JZqWF/1/

I am applying the overlay function into my page, and not sure about how the div works but it will create a div to highlight the element where i point to.

Comment: Can you also provide the html for that?

Comment: Would you please provide your HTML code?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
div.hopscotch-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: .3;
        background-color: #000;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
}
```

Or something to that effect. You need to specify where the div will be positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Give `left:0;` and `right:0` to cover white space.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set `left: 0`, `top: 0` and `bottom: 0`. It will fill the white space at bottom of the page.

```css
div.hopscotch-overlay
{
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .3;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div class="hopscotch-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working, i already update sample code i get from which used to apply in my page.